# Calculate Histogram in SQL Server Where There Are Missing Buckets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following dataset:

```
    | 0 |
    | 0 |
    | 0 |
    | 1 |
    | 1 |
    | 1 |
    | 1 |
    | 1 |
    | 1 |
    | 2 |
    | 2 |
    | 2 |
    | 2 |
    | 2 |
    | 2 |
    | 2 |
    | 3 |
    | 3 |
    | 3 |
    | 4 |
    | 4 |
    | 4 |
    | 4 |
    | 4 |
    | 4 |
    | 6 |
    | 6 |
    | 6 |
    | 7 |
    | 7 |
    | 7 |
    | 7 |
    | 8 |
    | 8 |
    | 8 |
    | 9 |
    | 9 |
    | 14 |
    | 16 |
    | 21 |
    | 28 |
    | 30 |
    | 32 |
    | 57 |
```

I have the following SQL Query:

```
select bucket_floor,
CONCAT(bucket_floor, ' to ', bucket_ceiling-1) as bucket_name,
count(*) as count
  from (
      select 
          floor([value]/5)*5 as bucket_floor,
          floor([value]/5)*5 + 5 as bucket_ceiling
      from @URQuartileDataRaw
        ) a
        group by bucket_floor, CONCAT(bucket_floor, ' to ', bucket_ceiling-1)
        order by bucket_floor;
```

When I run this I get the following:

```
    |Bucket_Name|Release_Count|
    |0 to 4     |25
    |5 to 9     |12
    |10 to 14   |1
    |15 to 19   |1
    |20 to 24   |1
    |25 to 29   |1
    |30 to 34   |2
    |55 to 59   |1
```

How can I insert buckets for 35 to 39, 40 to 44, 45 to 49, 50 to 54 since there is no data in the dataset for those, but I need them because this data feeds a chart?

I realized that all of the recommendations that were made assumed that I knew how many groupings I needed. I needed the buckets to be dynamic, so I came up with the following:

```
   declare @Buckets table(
   ROWID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   LowValue int,
   HiValue int
   )

   declare @Maxiteratons int = (Select ceiling(max([value])/5) from @QuartileDataRaw)

   -- Declare an iterator
   DECLARE @iteratons INT, @LowVal int = 0, @HiVal int = 4
   -- Initialize the iterator
   SET @iteratons = 0

    -- Loop through the rows of a table @myTable
   WHILE (@iteratons < @Maxiteratons)
       BEGIN
           insert into @Buckets (LowValue,HiValue)
           select @LowVal, @HiVal

           set @LowVal = @LowVal + 5
           set @HiVal = @HiVal + 5

           - Increment the iterator
           SET @iteratons = @iteratons + 1

       END

       ---- Get the number of rows in the looping table
       SET @Maxiteratons = (SELECT COUNT(ROWID) FROM @Buckets) 
       SET @iteratons = 1
       WHILE (@iteratons <= @Maxiteratons)
           BEGIN

                  -- Get the data from table and set to variables
                  SELECT @LowVal = LowValue, @HiVal = HiValue  FROM @Buckets WHERE ROWID = @iteratons

                  Insert into @DataTable (Bucket_Floor,Bucket_Name,Release_Count)

                  select 
                  @LowVal, CONCAT(@LowVal, ' to ', @HiVal),Count(*)
                  from @QuartileDataRaw
                  where [value] >= @LowVal
                  and [value] <= @HiVal

                  SET @iteratons = @iteratons + 1

                 END
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep my tiers in a generic table.  This removes the logic from the code and allows you to serve multiple masters by passing a parameter with regards to the TierGrp

**Example**

```
Declare @Tier table (TierGrp varchar(50),TierTitle varchar(50),TierR1 money,TierR2 money)
Insert Into @Tier values
 ('Sample','0 - 4'   ,0   ,5)
,('Sample','5 - 10'  ,5   ,10)
,('Sample','10 - 14' ,10  ,15)
,('Sample','15 - 19' ,15  ,20)
,('Sample','20 - 24' ,20  ,25)
,('Sample','25+'     ,25  ,999999)

Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (0),(0),(0),(1),(1),(15)

Select T.TierTitle
      ,ItemCnt = count(SomeCol)
 From  @Tier   T 
 Left  Join  @YourTable D on TierGrp='Sample' and SomeCol >=TierR1 and SomeCol <TierR2
 Group By T.TierR1,T.TierTitle
 Order By T.TierR1
```

**Returns**

```
TierTitle   ItemCnt
0 - 4       5
5 - 10      0
10 - 14     0
15 - 19     1
20 - 24     0
25+         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `values()` or something similar to generate the buckets and then use `left join`:

```
select v.bucket, count(dr.value)
from (values (0, 4, '0 to 4'),
             (5, 9, '5 to 9'),
             . . . 
     ) v(bucket, lo, hi) left join
     @URQuartileDataRaw dr
     on dr.value between v.lo and v.hi
group by v.bucket, v.lo
order by v.lo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table, put your query union queries of constants that generates 0 counts for every bucket, group by bucket_name, sum up the release_count.